# Python BeautifulSoup module not working with Django and Apache

Tags: python, django, apache

I am facing a very strange problem in my Django project.

My code uses the Python BeautifulSoup module to parse through a webpage. The call to the BeautifulSoup constructor seems to be working absolutely fine when the website is running on the Django development server, but when I switch to the Apache server the BeautifulSoup module no longer seems to work. Rest of my website, which is not using the BeautifulSoup module works absolutely fine. In fact when I comment out the call to the BeautifulSoup constructor and BeautifulSoup functions the web page opens without any problem when running on an Apache server. Having a call to BeautifulSoup constructor causes the webpage to be stuck at loading in the browser. I face no such problem when using the Django development server.

I know the question the problem seems very vague. I could not find any logical reason as to why it is getting stuck at a call to the BeautifulSoup constructor. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I am using the Python requests module too, which seems to be working fine on both the Django development server and the Apache server.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935589/beautifulsoup-inside-django-view-makes-wsgi-timeout.

Comment: @skyline75489 your suggestion worked! I cannot thank you enough for this, would have never guessed the cause myself.